# Cartoon where the main character gains powers from a special cat

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was this cartoon where the main kid character loved cats. I don't remember much, but I do remember that, later on, there was this one special cat he took care of, but then something risky happened and the cat gave him its powers, probably since the cat cared for his owner. The cat's power was dodging. I also remember the main character might have been in a subway? The cat was a special cat, and many enemies were after that cat, so he fought them. There was only one cat that was special. The cat was wounded in the first episode and when the main character saw the cat he took care of it. It was a black cat.

Comment: Can you remember roughly what year you watched this? Was this cat the only special one? Were there any other science fictional/fantastical things in the cartoon? Can you remember any specific plot points or the overarching plot? If you have the answers to any of those question or have anything else to add that you've remembered please [edit] those details into the question.